# Is there a way to update from legacy iTunes 12.6.5.3, or to continue using it, to get iOS 13 compatibility?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, upgrade

I have the legacy iTunes 12.6.5.3 on my 2011 MacBook Pro running Sierra. I have an iPhone SE running iOS 10.3.3. I'd like to upgrade my iPhone SE to iOS 13. In iTunes, it shows that the update is available to download and install, however I have heard about issues with this such as [this sending a phone into restore mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/ITunes/comments/d6p9tb/itunes_12653_ios_13/). However looking in the App Store, there was an "iTunes Device Support Update" which I then installed. Would this prevent the above problem? If not, how do I update iTunes on my Mac to the latest version, since it doesn't show up in the App Store for users of 12.6.5.3? I found that Apple has an installer for iTunes 12.8.2 to download, but is this the latest version for Sierra, and does it work properly with iOS 13.3?

Comment: May I ask why you want to update through iTunes? Just install it in the iPhones Settings app.

Comment: @X_841 - Some of us don't trust OTA as far as we can spit it. iTunes 12.6 also still has the apps. Apple has been forcing people more & more into pure OTA experience.  Some of us don't like being nannied to quite that extent. Also, using iTunes for updates of several similar devices is one download, many installs.

Comment: This thread on [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/cant-update-via-itunes-12-6-5-but-yes-we-can-with-a-trick.2199452/) indicates you can upgrade to iOS 13 OTA, then with the device update, still use iTunes 12.6 - I don't want to put it in as an answer because I cannot test it.

Comment: @X_841 I understand that is a possibility. Part of the reason is I'm thinking if it's handled by iTunes, then in the event of some kind of problem it would have the installer and a backup right there to try again or fix it, though not totally sure if that's how things work. Also I'd like to offload some of the work to my computer rather than be using my phone's wifi for several hours downloading the update, as my internet access is quite slow and wouldn't be so quick. Also I want to leave my options open in the future for similar updates if I want to use iTunes. So I want to have this option.

Comment: Ok sure, totally reasonable points. I was just thinking that doing it over iTunes is more work (especially now since you have to do research about it) than just update OTA - your choice though. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer then...